# how to eliminate arbitrary variables to form a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For instance,
$$y=Acos x+Bsin x$$
which satisfies the differential equation $$\dfrac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+y=0$$ which is of order 2 and has a solution that consists of two arbitrary constants.
I got a question which is $$y=c_{1}e^{x}+c_{2}xe^{x}$$
this has two arbitrary constants and I don't know how to eliminate two of them.I am always stuck with the constant "c1" no matter what how hard I try.Please suggest me a method to eliminate both of them

Comment: The appearance of terms $x^k e^{\alpha x}$, $k > 0$, suggests looking for a homogeneous linear differential equation whose characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)$ has a multiple root at $\lambda = \alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac {d^2}{dx^2}(e^{-x}y)=0$$ answers the question you asked, but I don’t know if that is the kind of answer you meant.